# How can I implement this Automaton in Java?

Tags: automaton

I want to implement this deterministic finite automaton in Java and I want the program the program to recognize the language of the automaton.
[Automaton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frX6V.png)

```
I already got this code, but I don´t no how to make the switch the best way :
```

int estado = 0;
         char c = 0;

```
     //else ir para erro
    switch(aOpcao) {
    case 1: 
        if(c == '/')  
    estado = 1;
     break;
    case 2: 
        if(c == '!')
        estado = 7; 
            if(c == '#') 
            estado = 6; 
         break;
    case 3:
        if(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f' 
        || c == 'g' || c == 'h' || c == 'i' || c == 'j' || c == 'k' ||
        c == 'l' || c == 'm' || c == 'n' || c == 'o' || c == 'p' || c == 'q' 
        || c == 'r' || c == 's' || c == 't' || c == 'u' || c == 'v' || c == 'w'
        || c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z' )
            estado = 8;
        if(c == '!')
            estado = 7;
        if(c == ',')
            estado = 14;
        if(c == 'a' || c == 'b' || c == 'c' || c == 'd' || c == 'e' || c == 'f' 
                || c == 'g' || c == 'h' || c == 'i' || c == 'j' || c == 'k' ||
                c == 'l' || c == 'm' || c == 'n' || c == 'o' || c == 'p' || c == 'q' 
                || c == 'r' || c == 's' || c == 't' || c == 'u' || c == 'v' || c == 'w'
                || c == 'x' || c == 'y' || c == 'z' )
        estado = 13;
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a better way to check if `c` is alphabet or not for those two long `if` statement.

then one simple way in java is to change it to

```
if( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') )
```

if you are talking about how to completely translate the above code into java. You have read java `switch()` statement and java documentation by yourself. Your question seems like a homework problem.